# VIM: has('macunix') or has('mac') do not work

Tags: macos, vim

I've moved from using MacVim to using vim in terminal on my MacOs Lion and I've realized that both:

```
has('macunix')
has('mac')
```

return false instead of true (they work fine within MacVim).
This is an issue because I use the same .vimrc on my Mac and on my Archlinux linode and need to set specific options based on the OS.

The only solution I could dig so far is to use the hostname() function to get the machine name and map it on a specific OS but it is not as elegant as being able to check the OS itself.

Anybody knows why the has('...') commands don't work as documented?

Comment: I'm going to guess that what's happening here is you are using the vim that is shipped with OSX instead of the terminal version of vim that's shipped with MacVim.  I strongly suggest you use the MacVim version as it's more up to date and has more features compiled in than the one that is shipped with OSX.  How did you install MacVim?

Comment: Do you mean calling mvim from terminal? This opens MacVim, I like to use vim in iterm2, with no gui. I also found a 'Vim' executable in /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS but it has the same issues described above. Lastly I don't really remember how I installed MacVim :(

Comment: `has('gui_macvim')` would return 1 only on MacVim, regardless if the GUI is running or not.

Comment: I'm now using the vim CLI that ships with MacVim and it recognizes properly has('mac') and has('macunix')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Randy Morris, use MacVim's bundled CLI executable.

However, here are a few lines from my `~/.vimrc`:

```
let os=substitute(system('uname'), '\n', '', '')
if os == 'Darwin' || os == 'Mac'
    set guifont=Inconsolata-dz:h12
    " more...
elseif os == 'Linux'
    set guifont=Inconsolata-dz\ Medium\ 10
    " more...
endif
```

On Mac OS X, `$ uname` returns `Darwin` when in X11/XQuartz and `Mac` otherwise.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. I'm still trying to figure out how to call the MacVim CLI executable (unless you mean calling mvim, I prefer to use vim from terminal with no gui)

Comment: 1. Put the `mvim` script distributed with MacVim somewhere in your `$PATH`. 2. Add `alias vim="mvim -v"` to your `~/.bashrc` or wherever you put your shell configuration. 3. Open a new terminal window. 4. `$ vim filename`. 5. Victory!

Comment: I use a symlink  `ln -s /path/to/mvim ~/bin/vim`.